Unable to upload Excel File without updated version of Rcpp
I am unable to load my excel file on R as it gives me the error below:
"Preparing data import requires an updated version of the Rcpp package. Do you want to install this package now?"

When I click on Yes it starts installing but never goes anywhere from there.

Run install.packages("Rcpp") and try again.

It doesnot work :|

You'll need to provide additional information. Please edit your question to include what is the output of the command I suggested.
